# Is there a URL path to files on device connected via bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, stream, android-mediaplayer, a2dp

I would like to stream music on multiple devices via Bluetooth. Therefore A2DP is not an option and SCO isn´t either due to insufficient sound quality. It is easy to stream music from a URL as schown [here](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class). Is it possible to set the URL for the android mediaplayer to a file on a different device connected via bluetooth? Alternatively is it possible to download the mp3 from the host device and play it at the same time? Thanks for any suggestions.